# How do you serve ember-cli from https://localhost:4200 in development

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

For our authentication to work with our ember app we need to serve the app from a secure url. We have a self signed ssl cert.

How do I setup the ember-cli to serve the index.html form a `https` domain.

Cheers

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/30574934/1392763.

If you will always use SSL you can set `"ssl": true` in the `.ember-cli` file for your project which will result in the `ember serve` command using SSL by default without having to pass the command line flag every time.

By default ember-cli will look in an **ssl** folder in the root of your project for **server.key** and **server.crt** files but you can customize that as well with the `--ssl-key` and `--ssl-cert` options to provide an alternate path.

If you don't already have a self signed SSL certificate for development you can follow these instructions to easily generate one: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-certificate-self

Example **.ember-cli**:

```
{
  "disableAnalytics": false,
  // Use SSL for development server by default
  "ssl": true,
  "ssl-key": "path/to/server.key",
  "ssl-cert": "path/to/server.crt"
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this and keep getting `permission denied, open 'ssl/server.key'` - I've tried chowning and am still having trouble. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Interesting, are you using a self signed / self generated cert or a real ssl cert?

Comment: Self-generated - my issue was that you have start ember w/ `sudo` if you want it to boot up on the default SSL port. I don't recommend doing this as it means a lot of your files get owned by root and it's a headache, though in a pinch it did the trick.

Comment: Ah ok, yeah you do have to run as `sudo` if you are trying to serve on port 443 (default secure port).  However you can run with HTTPS/SSL on ember-cli's default port of 4200 for the `ember serve` command.

Answer (score 4):

### **EDIT**

***For googlers, this is no longer true. Use ember-cli --ssl***

Thx to **xdumaine** Jul 12 at 10:08***

<del>emphasized textYou can't directly from ember-cli without putting your hand in the code which I don't recommend :)</del>

<del>If you want to go this way look at: `node_modules/ember-cli/lib/tasks/server/express-server.js` and may be also into `node_modules/ember-cli/lib/tasks/server/livereload-server.js`</del>

### For those who still want to go through a web server :

However there are other cleaner solutions, for example use nginx as a (reverse) proxy :) or ever serving directly from nginx on the /dist folder :)
Reverse basic example with nginx (didn't tried with ssl but should theoretically work :p) :

```
server {
   listen 443;
   server_name *.example.com;
   ssl on;
   ssl_certificate /path/to/your/certificate.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key /path/to/your/key.key;
   location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:4200;
   }
}
```

I said nginx but actually any webserver can do the trick right :)

**NaB DO NOT USE `ember serve` IN PRODUCTION**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I agree I would never run ember server in production. I need `https` for  `development` and `test` environments. Given that will nginx work in a local mac environment?

Comment: Yes i think it would :) it's quite easy to setup and it's "free" so the best way is to give it a try.

Comment: For googlers, this is no longer true. Use `ember-cli --ssl`

Answer (score 0):

I use the [tunnels](https://github.com/jugyo/tunnels) gem with [pow port-proxying](http://pow.cx/manual.html#section_2.1.4).

#### Update: more detail

Using a real web server (like the previous answer with nginx) is a great way to go, and is probably more like your production setup. However, I manage a lot of different projects, and am not that interested in managing an nginx configuration file for all of my projects. Pow makes it easy to make a lot of different projects available on port 80 on one development machine.

[Pow](http://pow.cx/) has two main modes. The primary function is to be a simple server for Rack applications, accessed via a custom local domain such as `http://my-application.dev/`. This is done by symlinking `~/.pow/my-application` to a directory that contains a rack application. However, pow can also proxy requests to a custom local domain to a specified port by creating a file that contains only the port number (such as `echo 4200 > ~/.pow/my-application`). This makes it easy to develop locally with an actual domain (also, as a side note, subdomains work too, which is really handy; for example, `foobar.my-application.dev` will also route to `my-application`).

[Tunnels](https://github.com/jugyo/tunnels) makes it easy to use pow with https.

#### Setup

```
# Install pow
curl get.pow.cx | sh

# Set up pow proxy for your ember app
echo 4200 > ~/.pow/my-application

# Start your ember server
ember serve # specify a port here if you used something else for pow proxy
# Check that http://my-application.dev correctly shows your ember app in the browser

# Install tunnels
gem install tunnels # possibly with sudo depending on your ruby setup

# Start tunnels
sudo tunnels

# Now https://my-application.dev should work
```

Comment: Amiel Can you explain this setup a bit more?