# broccoli serve on https

Tags: https, npm, broccolijs

I've searched everywhere but can not come up with a solution for my issue. I want to serve files from my local serve using broccoli but since the files are to be tested on a secure (https) url, my browser throws an error.

Is there any way to serve broccoli on https so I can access my files like this:
https://localhost:4220/app.js

Comment: Is it possible to click through the error and ignore it? This may be happening because broccoli is using a self-signed certificate, in which case for testing purposes you can tell the browser to accept it anyway.

Comment: Thanks @Maximillian Laumeister. I've been able to bypass the browsers error and test accordingly. I still would really like to serve my file over https from broccoli. The error I'm getting is 


`Mixed Content: The page at 'https://environment_being_tested' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://localhost:4200/my_file.js'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.`


Any insights on how I can go about this?

Comment: How are you including the script on your page? In the case that you are using a script tag like the following: `<script src="http://example.com/my_file.js"></script>` then you can change it to be protocol agnostic to fix the mixed content warning: `<script src="//example.com/my_file.js"></script>`

Comment: @KennethKogi Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @NudeCanalTroll, I have not. It's actually a project that I want to get started on adding to broccoli or as a broccoli plugin. I have an idea and with a little help from others, I'd want to add some form of enhancement.  Any takers?

Answer (score 0):

I learnt that you can start any broccoli applications using ember. In that case, run if you follow the steps on this [ember-cli question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952627/how-do-you-serve-ember-cli-from-https-localhost4200-in-development), it should work on your broccoli application. I hope this helps someone out there. 
Goodluck!!